# Include blockquote in rmarkdown ioslides

Tags: r, r-markdown, ioslides

I would like to include a `blockquote` in an RMarkdown `ioslides` presentation but the RMarkdown syntax for `blockquote` doesn't seem to work for `ioslides_presentation` output.

This is my code:

```
---
title: "La recherche reproductible"
date: '2017-08-06'
output: 
  ioslides_presentation:
    css: style_presentation.css
---

## First slide 

> Every project you work on, always at least have one collaborator, and that's future you.
Hadley Wickham, chief scientist at RStudio
```

Here is a screenshot of my output. [image]

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5):

I've only now stumbled across your post from 1.5 years ago, with a similar requirement/question (how to get blockquotes in an `ioslides` presentation).

For what it's (still) worth, here's what I've come up with.

First we add a custom `blockquote` style to the CSS file (adapted from [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/simple-and-nice-blockquote-styling/)):

```
blockquote {
  background: #f9f9f9;
  border-left: 5px solid #ccc;
  margin: 1.5em 10px;
  padding: 0.5em 1.5em;
}
```

Then assuming `styles.css` is the CSS file containing above `blockquote` styling

```
---
title: "La recherche reproductible"
date: '2017-08-06'
output:
  ioslides_presentation:
    css: styles.css
---

## First slide

<blockquote>
Every project you work on, always at least have one collaborator, and that's future you.
Hadley Wickham, chief scientist at RStudio
</blockquote>
```

produces

[image]

Or slightly more concise (thanks to @KonradRudolph), we can use the usual `>` syntax with the custom CSS

```
> Every project you work on, always at least have one collaborator, and that's future you.
> Hadley Wickham, chief scientist at RStudio
```

Comment: Are you sure the `> …` syntax doesn’t produce a blockquote that just requires some custom CSS?

Comment: @KonradRudolph Ah yes you're right. Instead of `<blockquote>...</blockquote>` we can use `> ...`. We still need the custom CSS though. I've made an edit.